# Specific Heat Capacity in the 2D Ising model of spin glass

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models

I am studying statistical mechanics on my own and I read that the 2D Ising model can be used to model spin glass thermal properties.
I looked at Onsager's formula for free energy there are some points that I couldnt understand

1-why is the heat capacity per spin called specific heat capacity per spin. are the units[J/K] or [J/(kgK)]? the solution is derived from the internal energy derivative with respect to tempareature which came from free energy so the units [J/K] is reasonable to me

2-how is this heat capacity compared with phononic heat capacity it seems to me that it is very large in magnitude if we account for all N unit cells in a sample if each atom is associated with a spin

[image]